# I am trying to find my iphone . Will the find my phone through icloud work

Tags: iphone

I am using the find my iphone app to locate my lost i phone.does my iphone have to be on to find it with the find my iphone app

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the iPhone needs to be powered (from battery), turned on and have a cell or WiFi signal in order to update its position in the Find My iPhone app.

Comment: And if it is not on it will report the last location and indicate that it is currently not responding